# Tooltip + modal in button - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-placement="bottom" rel="tooltip" title="Info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button>
```

Got modal and tooltip in 1 button. After modal is being closed, tooltip is being shown. I don't want that. I'm trying to achieve with this code:

```
$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip('manual');
     if (!$('#myModal').is(':visible')) {
         $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
     }
```

Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Triggering the tooltip that way holds the focus after the modal pops up, this code should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: "hover"});
});
```

Answer (score 10):

actually this is not the best approach to achieve what you want you can do it in another way check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sso79Ldj/1/)

just wrap your `btn` in a span which will trigger the modal

```
<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-placement="bottom" title="Info" data-toggle="tooltip">Launch demo modal</button>
</span>
```

Comment: This  worked for me and it is also simple.

Comment: Worked nicely with Bootstrap 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help?

```
<!-- PROMOTE BUTTON JS-->
$('[id="promote"],[id="demote"]').click(function(){
    $('#smallmodal').modal('show');
});
<!-- END PROMOTE BUTTON JS-->
```

When you click button with `id="promote"` or `id="demote"` it will trigger the modal with `id="smallmodal"` and show Tooltip.

```
<button class="item"  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#smallmodal-promote" title="Demote Image" name="demote" id="demote" value="">
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-download"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

what I did this in bootstrap 5:

```
<a type="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Info">
   <span class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal" >Modal</span>
</a>
```